# Kernel dies after using np.logical_and

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, cell

So I have created a sample dataset that is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = range(1, 10)
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
arr2 = np.random.randint(x)
arr3 = np.random.randint(x)
arr4 = np.random.randint(x)


dict_df = {
    'arr1' : arr1,
    'arr2' : arr2,
    'arr3' : arr3,
    'arr4' : arr4
}


df = pd.DataFrame(dict_df)
```

When printed this works fine, though when I try to add:

```
filt = np.logical_and(df['arr1']==0, df['arr2']==0, df['arr3']==0)
```

the kernel dies, (at the top of the screen it says Dead Kernel) Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Ran your code in Jupyter Notebook and VS Code, it worked just fine.

Comment: @NYC coder I ment to add a third item to the np.logical_and(), if could, please see if you can run it again.

Comment: if you look at the doc of [logical_and](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html#numpy.logical_and), you can only pass two items called x1 and x2 in the doc, not a third item

Comment: @Ben.T Is there another method or way to pass 3 items?

Comment: @benito.cano see the answer of NYC Coder :)

Comment: The third argument is the output. Therefore the result of anding first two arguments is stored to a temporary array and goes to data heaven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.logical_and` takes only 2 parameters. Try this instead

```
filt = (df['arr1']==0) & (df['arr2']==0) & (df['arr3']==0)
print(filt)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

use `ufunc.reduce` on `np.logical_and`

```
s = np.logical_and.reduce([df['arr1']==0, df['arr2']==0, df['arr3']==0])

Out[85]: array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False])
```